# Why is this considered a simple select despite the use of a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

If I run this query into my MySQL database:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Orders
    NATURAL JOIN Order_Details
WHERE
    QuotedPrice > 1000
    AND
    OrderDate BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-31';
```

it says that the select_type for both databases is "SIMPLE".

From what I know, a SIMPLE select_type would suggest that there are not any joins being used, but of course, there is a natural join in that statement.

Can someone please explain to me the possible reasoning behind this?

Comment: What is the schema of both tables?

Comment: From the MySQL documentation: "The NATURAL [LEFT] JOIN of two tables is defined to be semantically equivalent to an INNER JOIN or a LEFT JOIN with a USING clause that names all columns that exist in both tables." - this sounds like overkill and probably not what is intended. Is there a reason you're not using a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead?

Comment: No one outside of academia *ever* uses NATURAL JOIN. The two biggest drawbacks  1) forcing every future reader of the SQL to go and look at the table definitions to find every column that has a matching name, to figure out what the join is actually doing and 2) the potential for the query to stop working when more columns are added to the tables... and this essentially prohibits identically named, common housekeeping columns like `last_updated_dt`, `updated_by`, etc. )... the drawbacks far outweigh any perceived benefit. No SQL professionals *ever* use a NATURAL JOIN.

Comment: @spencer7593 is right. Torturing the people who work on your software after you is, to borrow a phrase from Edsger Dijkstra, considered harmful.

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm at uni doing this stuff so that's probably why we're using it haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SIMPLE` just means that the table access is not using any UNION operations and not using any subqueries.

Just put aside whatever it is you think that `SIMPLE` suggests. And go with what the MySQL Reference Manual says. Brief explanation of the values that appear in the `select_type` column:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html